# Problema na ordem do select

Tags: php, sql, select

Alimentei este gráfico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas estou com o um problema no select dele

```
<?php
    $sql_2_vis = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT data, uniques, pageviews FROM tb_visitas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7") or die(mysqli_error($config));

    if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_2_vis) <= '0'){
        echo "
            <div class=\"col-lg-6\">
                <div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
                    <strong>Erro!</strong> $erro
                </div>
            </div>                  
        ";  
    }else{
        $count_vis = 0;
        while($r_sql_2_vis = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2_vis)){
            $data_sel      = $r_sql_2_vis[0];
            $uniques_sel   = $r_sql_2_vis[1];
            $pageviews_sel = $r_sql_2_vis[2];

            if($count_vis++) echo ', ';
            echo '["' . date("d/m", strtotime($data_sel)) . '",' . $uniques_sel . ']';
        }
    }
?>
```

Seria necessário exibir, neste caso, 05/05, 06/05, 07/05...
E está ao contrário.

Se eu der um `ORDER BY id ASC`, ele vai pegar os primeiros registros.
Vi em alguns lugares que é possível fazer um select dentro do select, mas não deu certo também.

Comment: verifica no gráfico que deve ter opção de inverter a exibição

Comment: Caso  sua pergunta tenha sido respondida, favor escolher a resposta para finalizar a pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

A seguinte query irá funcionar:

```
SELECT data, uniques, pageviews 
FROM ( SELECT data FROM tb_visitas ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 7 ) aux 
ORDER BY aux.data ASC 
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Tem como arruma-la. Pera ai.

Comment: Boa... Mas acho que é ASC. Lembre que o resultado é...  05/05, 06/05, 07/05..

Comment: Bem lembrado, faltou corrigir o segundo order by. Obrigado @AndreiCoelho

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `array_reverse()`:

```
$count_vis = 0;
while($r_sql_2_vis = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2_vis)){
    $row[]=array('data_sel'=>$r_sql_2_vis[0],'uniques_sel'=>$r_sql_2_vis[1],'pageviews_sel'=>$r_sql_2_vis[2]);
}
$row=array_reverse($row);
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $data_sel      = $value['data_sel'];
    $uniques_sel   = $value['uniques_sel'];
    $pageviews_sel = $value['pageviews_sel'];

    if($count_vis++) echo ', ';
    echo '["' . date("d/m", strtotime($data_sel)) . '",' . $uniques_sel . ']';
}
```

> [Referência da função **array_reverse()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 2):

Além das outras respostas, para fazer de forma crescente (ASC) basta você colocar o inicio da data que pegará nos registro e ordenar pela data.

Por data:

```
SELECT data, uniques, pageviews FROM tb_visitas 
WHERE data >= '05/05/2018' 
ORDER BY data ASC LIMIT 7
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$dataInicial = "05/05/2018";
$sql_2_vis = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT data, uniques, pageviews FROM tb_visitas WHERE data >= '$dataInicial' ORDER BY data ASC LIMIT 7") or die(mysqli_error($config));
```

Comment: não discordo da resposta do @DavidAlves seja boa, porém o DESC vai trazer os ultimos resultados, não invertê-los

Comment: @WeesSmith tem rasão. Ele teria que colocar em ASC só isso.

Comment: Ele quer os resultados de ASC de forma invertida, por isso sugeri o array_reverse

Comment: @WeesSmith alias, se ele colocar em ASC ele terá que iniciar de uma data de qualquer jeito...

Comment: @WeesSmith ele quer as datas de forma crescente 05/05, 06/05, 07/05...  certo?

Comment: Sim, ele pode colocar outra condição no WHERE tbm, assim como vc sugeriu, tbm vai rodar da forma esperada

Comment: @WeesSmith exato. Pensamos igual então =)

Comment: Sim, e acredito que usando a data seja mais efetivo, por não precisar de dois loops como no meu exemplo

Comment: @WeesSmith e na verdade a resposta dele (david) está errada.

Comment: Sim, está errada

Comment: Eu discordo de vocês :P
Visto que não está muito bem explicado o real interesse da consulta, pelo que eu entendi ele quer os resultados dos últimos 7 dias para exibir no gráfico. Dessa forma, pegando DESC pela data e limit 7 resolve sim o problema dele. No caso da pergunta, ele gostaria de inverter os resultados que tem justamente porque obteve os últimos 7 dias na ordem inversa à desejada.

Comment: @DavidAlves resolveria se fosse de ordem decrescente.. o Resultado que ele quer é... 05/05, 06/05, 07/05.... ou seja, crescente.

Comment: @DavidAlves esse resultado ele já tem... 11/05, 10/05, etc...

Comment: Verdade, corrigi minha resposta.

Comment: Falei do erro do @DavidAlves mas estava comentendo o mesmo erro. kkkkk

Comment: Acontece hahaha